# MySQL - INNER JOIN with SELECT not giving expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now but my level of SQL knowledge is blocking me.
I have to get some information from a few tables and I wish I could just just post here my tables but the system does not let me however maybe my question can be answered by looking at that I have.

I am trying to get a listing of Customer Quotes with a total per Quote while each Quote have a number of products. If I do this I get the proper result as far as the totals per Quote:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM((lineItems.prodPrice + lineItems.prodTax1 + lineItems.prodTax2 + lineItems.prodTax3) * lineItems.prodQty),2) AS price 
  FROM lineItems 
 GROUP 
    BY transId
```

So far so good but now I need to get the customer name, Quote#, Quote date from other tables.
If I do this I get an error:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM((lineItems.prodPrice + lineItems.prodTax1 + lineItems.prodTax2 + lineItems.prodTax3) * lineItems.prodQty),2) AS price,customers.name,transactions.qteNum,transactions.qteDate FROM lineItems GROUP BY transId
INNER JOIN customers ON transactions.custId = customers.cid
INNER JOIN lineItems ON lineItems.transId = transactions.tid
```

If I remove the GROUP BY there is no more error but I get a single line with a global total.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: It may also be useful to know what error you are receiving.

Comment: How do you know which quote belongs to which total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you can't use a `GROUP BY` between `FROM` and the JOINS.
Furthermore you used the table `lineItems` in the last INNER JOIN instead of `transactions`.

I suggest you a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    ROUND(SUM((lineItems.prodPrice + lineItems.prodTax1 + lineItems.prodTax2 + lineItems.prodTax3) * lineItems.prodQty),2) AS price,
    customers.name,
    transactions.qteNum,
    transactions.qteDate
FROM lineItems
INNER JOIN transactions ON lineItems.transId = transactions.tid
INNER JOIN customers ON transactions.custId = customers.cid
GROUP BY customers.name, transactions.qteNum, transactions.qteDate
```